# variable in observable object not accessible after declaration (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am making an app with SwiftUI and Firestore. Within the Firestore-Database, I save 'householdID's. When a specific page of the app appears, the householdID is set within a repository-class, so that in future function calls, this householdID is already set:

```
var body: some View {
  VStack {
    ...
    }}.onAppear(perform: {
        self.postListVM.postRepository.initHousehold(housholdID: self.session.session?.householdID ?? "")
    })
  }
}
```

When i print out the local variable inside of the initHousehold(...) method, the householdID is saved to my local variable.

The problem I have, is that when I now try to access the local variable householdID inside of my postRepository-class (by calling the addVote(..) method), it says, that the variable is empty:

```
class PostRepository: ObservableObject {
  var householdID: String? = ""
  
  func initHousehold(hid: String) {
    householdID = hid
    print(self.householdID) //prints Optional("LR2GuZaikjxb5Xq5yGBc")
  }

  func addVote(post: Post, option: Int, counter: Int) {
      print(self.householdID) //prints Optional("")
  }
```

I am calling the addVote-function inside another class like this:

```
...
@Published var postRepository = PostRepository()
...
postRepository.addVote(...)
...
```

I am struggling with this bug for hours and can't figure out, where the problem might be.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Would you show code/views where `PostRepository` is instantiated?

Comment: I am instantiating PostRepository inside two different classes, both with the following code: ``@Published var postRepository = PostRepository()``. Might that be the problem? I thought that with the use of ``@Published``, i would have something like a singelton?

Comment: I assume you just create two different instances in these two places, so they, obviously, live independently. Instead you have to use one instane in both places, as they, seems, dependent.

Comment: you are right, that was the problem. I had to make a public variable. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I instantiated the PostRepository at two different locations. I solved the problem, by declaring a global variable instead.